# Basic UNION or JOIN

Tags: sql, union

I've worked out some queries that are pulling the data I want, but I can't seem to put them together. I'd like to have all the information in one table.

```
SELECT MarketIdentifier, CurveType, VintageYear, Rate = Avg(RateValue) FROM #RateCurves GROUP BY MarketIdentifier, CurveType, VintageYear ORDER BY MarketIdentifier, CurveType, VintageYear

SELECT MarketIdentifier, CurveType, VintageYear, Obligation = Avg(ObligationValue) FROM #ObligationCurves GROUP BY MarketIdentifier, CurveType, VintageYear ORDER BY MarketIdentifier, CurveType, VintageYear
```

The above two select statements result in two different tables, one with the following headers:

```
MarketIdentifier, CurveType, VintageYear, Rate
```

the other with:

```
MarketIdentifier, CurveType, VintageYear, Obligation
```

I simply want the output to be:

```
MarketIdentifier, CurveType, VintageYear, Obligation, Rate
```

I've attempted a number of different combinations of JOIN, UNION, UNION ALL, etc. Some of which result in the desired table format but incorrect values. I'm sure this is something very basic I'm missing.

Comment: Are MarketIdentifier, CurveType, VintageYear the same on all rows?

Comment: Can you show some sample data? Are MarketIdentifier, CurveType and VintageYear in both tables the same - if I get the rateValue and ObligationValue for the same MarketIdentifier, CurveType and VintageYear, do they refer to the same logical entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to put the `group by` results in derived tables `t1` and `t2` and to then join by the columns you're grouping by.

The query below assumes that both queries have 1 row for each (MarketIdentifier, CurveType, VintageYear) combination. i.e. there won't be a (MarketIdentifier, CurveType, VintageYear) that's in one table but not the other. Otherwise you'll have to do a left or full join depending on which rows you need.

```
select * from (
    your first query here
) t1 inner join (
    your second query here
) t2 on t2.MarketIdentifier = t1.MarketIdentifier
and t2.CurveType = t1.CurveType
and t2.VintageYear = t1.VintageYear
```

Comment: This worked! The only problem is it duplicated the MarketIdentifier, CurveType, and VintageYear columns. Regardless this will work for my purposes, maybe I can figure out how to get rid of the duplicated columns.

Comment: And I figured out out - Just had to select specific columns instead of select *. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the same fields in both sentences. Try it:

```
SELECT MarketIdentifier, CurveType, VintageYear, NULL as Obligation , Rate = Avg(RateValue) 
FROM #RateCurves 
GROUP BY MarketIdentifier, CurveType, VintageYear 
ORDER BY MarketIdentifier, CurveType, VintageYear
UNION
SELECT MarketIdentifier, CurveType, VintageYear, Obligation = Avg(ObligationValue), NULL as Rate
FROM #ObligationCurves 
GROUP BY MarketIdentifier, CurveType, VintageYear 
ORDER BY MarketIdentifier, CurveType, VintageYear;
```

Comment: After removing the first ORDER BY this worked, but doubled up all the rows and listed NULL for Rate or Obligation, depending on which one was showing a value.